# Review of Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy Content

Tags: reference-request, learning-methods

Although it calls itself an encyclopedia, the [Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy](http://plato.stanford.edu) is a collection of articles in varying formats (expository, historical, literature reviews, lecture-style). I am wondering if there has been any attempt at producing metadata about this resource to make it easier to use the Encyclopedia as a survey resource instead of a tool for more in depth research. I ask this, because although Wikipedia provides extensive survey material, there are many cases where the Stanford Encyclopedia may cover narrower topics within the philosophical landscape.

Comment: Since the SEP is a product of a private institution, perhaps you might contact the editorial board, there are phones and emails in the page (https://plato.stanford.edu/board.html). And perhaps you can share your findings here. You have a point there, I personally use both, among others, always from a critical standpoint.